# Catching errors from nested async/await functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I have a function chain in a `node 4.3` script that looks something like, callback -> promise -> async/await -> async/await -> async/await

like so:

```
const topLevel = (resolve, reject) => {
    const foo = doThing(data)
    .then(results => {
        resolve(results)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        reject(err)
    })
}

async function doThing(data) {
    const thing = await doAnotherThing(data)
    return thing
}

async function doAnotherThing(data) {
    const thingDone = await etcFunction(data)
    return thingDone
}
```

(The reason it isn't `async/await` all the way through is that the top level function is a task queue library, and ostensibly can't be run `async/await` style)

If `etcFunction()` throws, does the `error` bubble up all the way to the top-level `Promise`?

If not, how can I bubble-up `errors`? Do I need to wrap each `await` in a `try/catch` and `throw` from there, like so?

```
async function doAnotherThing(data) {
   try {
     await etcFunction(data)
   } catch(err) {
     throw err  
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `makePromise`?

Comment: "*the top level function is a task queue library, and ostensibly can't be run async/await style*" - there's no reason why a queue library couldn't use `async function`s as tasks. You really shouldn't have to deal with callbacks. If you need to use a particular queue library that employs callback style, use a wrapper function.

Comment: @Bergi `makePromise` is actually an `async` function, but since it's called from a non-`async` environment, i'm handling it like a promise.  re: i agree, I'm going to try and promise-ify it eventually, but can I have reliable error bubbling in the mean time?

Comment: @Bergi i removed the `makePromise` bit from the snippet to clarify--the first function called in the top-level is an `async function` i'm treating as a regular `Promise`

Comment: So it's a promise-returning *function* and needs to be `makePromise()` not `makePromise`. I see.

Comment: @Bergi yes, thanks for catching that & the other errors- i should've just copied the actual code instead of trying to recreate in pseudocode

Comment: FYI, async/await is not part of ES7. It will be released next year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If `etcFunction()` throws, does the error bubble up all the way through the `async function`s?

Yes. The promise returned by the outermost function will be rejected. There's no need to do `try { … } catch(e) { throw e; }`, that's just as pointless as it would be in synchronous code.

> … bubble up all the way to the top-level Promise?

No. Your `topLevel` contains multiple mistakes. If you don't `return` the `doThing(data)` from the `then` callback, it will be ignored (not even awaited) and the rejection stays unhandled. You'll have to use

```
.then(data => { return doThing(data); })
// or
.then(data => doThing(data))
// or just
.then(doThing) // recommended
```

And in general, your function should look like this:

```
function toplevel(onsuccess, onerror) {
    makePromise()
    .then(doThing)
    .then(onsuccess, onerror);
}
```

No unnecessary function expressions, no [`.then(…).catch(…)` antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) (that could lead to `onsuccess` and `onerror` to *both* be called).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but as your question is written, wouldn't the `doAnotherThing()` function be unnecessary because it just wraps `etcFunction()`?

So your code could be simplified to this:

```
async function topLevel(){
  let thing = await doThing(data)
  let thingDone = await etcFunction(data)
  //Everything is done here...
}

//Everything starts here...
topLevel()
```

Comment: I think this is mock code to demonstrate nested await calls

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue where my nested errors didn't appear to bubble up to my top level function.

**The fix for me was to remove the "try / catch" from my nested function and allow the error to just be thrown.**